# Update message in google chat from Jira

Tags: jira, google-hangouts

I am trying to create a notification in google chat whenever the status of a jira ticket changes.  I have managed to sort the automation so that a message is sent to google chat every time the status changes but it creates a new thread each time.  I would like to either update the original message with the new status or add a new message to the same thread.

I have the Automation configured to Send web request as follows has anyone managed to do this?

Webhook URL : https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/xxxx/messages?key=xxxx&token=xxxx
Header : Content-Type - application/json; charset=UTF-8

HTTP method : POST
Webhook body : Custom data

Custom data

```
"cards": [
 {
   "header": {
     "title": "{{issue.key}}",
     "subtitle": "{{issue.summary}}"
   },
   "sections": [
     {
       "widgets": [
           {
             "keyValue": {
               "topLabel": "Reported by",
               "content": "{{issue.reporter.displayName}}"
               }
           },
           {
             "keyValue": {
               "topLabel": "Status",
               "content": "{{issue.status.name}}"
             }
           }
       ]
     },
     {
       "widgets": [
           {
               "buttons": [
                 {
                   "textButton": {
                     "text": "View Ticket",
                     "onClick": {
                       "openLink": {
                         "url": "{{issue.url.customer}}"
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               ]
           }
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
]
}
```

[Example of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYxTk.png)

Answer (score 0):

### To create a new message under the same thread, you need to provide the [thread](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages#thread) as part of the [message body](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create#query-parameters)

- When you send the first message, the response contains a `message resource` that contains a `thread resource`
- Include the thread name you obtain after sending the first message into the message body of the subsequent messages - this will enforce threading

**To update an existing card, you need to follow the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick#responding_to_clicks_with_a_new_or_updated_message):**

- Use the `actionResponse.type` `UPDATE_MESSAGE` instead of `NEW_MESSAGE`
- I am not sure how you trigger an action response in your situation, but if you have a functionality that is able to trigger a new message, you can just as well trigger `UPDATE_MESSAGE` instead